# Dynamic Splitter Panes

Tags: docking, splitter, panes

How would I go about implementing dynamic/docking splitter panes in a vb.net app similar to visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following demo at ZettaCube, their WebDock component seems to have functionalities close to VS.NET, especially docking and auto-hide.

http://www.zettacube.com/

Comment: zetta is now out of business.

Answer (score 1):

[DockPanel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite) is one painless & open source way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

DockPanel is for WinForms only.  Seems that the WebDock from zettacube above is the only solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily is the short answer.

A high level idea would be to define some regions using divs or a table and using your js framework of choice make these elements resizeable.   that gets you the splitter aspect.

The docking will have to use absoluting positioned elements that you can drag and drop and if you are currently over a docking element, reposition the element to be docked to inside the docking element and change it's position back to normal.  When you want to drag it out you will change it's positioning back to absolute

Also, this is not easy to do and will take a long time and still probably not work correctly.  Sorry to sound pessimistic though.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use some of the already available controls out there.

I use the control library from Janus Controls, but there are dozens out there to choose from.

http://www.janusys.com/controls/

Agree with Nick, this is not something you just throw together yourself.